# Matlab C-DLL, char* type to send image data truncated

Tags: c, matlab, pointers, shared-libraries, loadlibrary

I am using loadlibrary to interface with a DLL that returns image data in a struct containing info about the size of the image and a field where the actual image data is stored:

```
struct ImageStruct
{
    // vertical size of the image [pixel]
    int imageHeight;

    // horizontal size of the image [pixel]
    int imageWidth;

    // image data size [byte]
    int imageSize;

    // pointer to image data
    char * imageBuffer;
};
```

Matlab turns that into the following statement in the proto file:

```
structs.ImageStruct.members=struct('imageHeight', 'int32', 'imageWidth', 'int32', 'imageSize', 'int32', 'imageBuffer', 'cstring');
```

I then instantiate such a struct using `str = libstruct('ImageStruct',[]) % default initialized` and pass it, through `calllib` to a C function which takes a pointer to such a struct and fills it with image data. The problem is that my image data can contain zeros. Matlab automatically turns the char* member into a char array, stopping at the first 0 it encounters. This means my image data gets truncated. I however know how many values there are, this is returned in the imageSize member. How do I access the whole array?

I have found one solution, changing the type of the `imageBuffer` member in the proto file to `uint8Ptr` and then telling matlab what number of elements should be read from the pointer:

```
str.imageBuffer.setdatatype(str.imageBuffer.DataType,1,str.imageSize);
```

Is there a better solution?